# NHibernate - using custom sql query for a column

Tags: nhibernate

Is there any way to use custom sql with NHibernate? I want to use a complex sql for a specific column.

Example:

```
select id, viewsCount, commentsCount, 
  0.2 * viewsCount / (select top 1 viewsCount from articles where isActive = 1 order by viewsCount DESC) as priorityViews, 
  0.8 * commentsCount / (select top 1 commentsCount from articles where isActive = 1 order by commentsCount DESC) as priorityComments, 
  round(0.2 * viewsCount / (select top 1 viewsCount from articles where isActive = 1 order by viewsCount DESC) +  
  0.8 * commentsCount / (select top 1 commentsCount from articles where isActive = 1 order by commentsCount DESC), 1) as priority
from articles
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in your mapping with the [formula attribute](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-property), or in your query with [Projections.SqlProjection()](http://insightfultech.blogspot.com/2008/07/projectionssqlprojection-with.html)